# multiple records insertion with dynamically created input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Basically this what I do using eloqouent when saving new record unto my database (refer below)

```
$item = new item();
$item->name = $request->name;
$item->description = $request->description;
$item->rating = $request->rating;
$item->save();
```

but I came across unto scenario where input fields are created dynamically so this is my script for that

```
$(document).on("click", "#create_input", function(){
    $("form fieldset").append('<input type="text" name="name" value="" /><input type="text" name="description" value="" /><input type="text" name="rating" value="" />');
});
```

and my default form is (refer below)

```
<button id="#create_input">Create new field</button>
<form action="{{ url('/item/add') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="description" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="rating" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

so if user click the button "create new field", another input fields (name, description, rating) will be added unto the form fieldset.

so how can i save it like save 2 records at the same time (assume i have 2 sets of fieldsets of name, description, rating)? depends on the number of fields currently present unto the form then also the number of insertion e.g. I have 4 fieldsets of rating, description, rating then 4 records will be inserted. Any ideas, help?

Comment: Use input arrays. And use loops.

Comment: so can you post a reference or a sample please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `[]` with the name of the input field e.g. `name="discription[]"` in your form as well as in javascript click event handler.

And then in the saving part just use the loop

```
$c = count($request->name[]);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
   $item = new item();
   $item->name = $request->name[$i];
   $item->description = $request->description[$i];
   $item->rating = $request->rating[$i];
   $item->save();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i got this error Cannot use [] for reading after trying your code

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($c);` and `var_dump($request->name);`?  What is the output of them?

Answer (score 2):

Use input arrays. And use loops. Define the fields like -

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="description[]" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="rating[]" value="" />
</fieldset>
```

jQuery -

```
$(document).on("click", "#create_input", function(){
    $("form fieldset").append('<input type="text" name="name[]" value="" /><input type="text" name="description[]" value="" /><input type="text" name="rating[]" value="" />');
});
```

When the form is posted you will get the values something like -

```
array(
   name -> array(
              0 -> 'aaa',
              1 -> 'bbb',
              2 -> 'ccc',
           )
   description -> array(
              0 -> 'aaa',
              1 -> 'bbb',
              2 -> 'ccc',
           )
...........
)
```

Then you can loop through them and save them accordingly.

Comment: any example or reference how to do the looping please?